# Color blindness simulation real-time

Tags: windows, colors

Can I simulate color blindess in real-time? The found some software but it doesn't do it real-time. I thought about turning down the saturation of a single color but I'm not sure if it has accurate results or how do to it. My monitor doesn't give an option to change single colors.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

There is software for that, for example
[Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/) :

> Color Oracle is a free color blindness simulator for Windows, Mac and Linux. It takes the guesswork out of designing for color blindness by showing you in real time what people with common color vision impairments will see.

You will find much more information and advice in the post
[How do I simulate color blindness for accessibility testing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77605/how-do-i-simulate-color-blindness-for-accessibility-testing)

Comment: Also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=color+blind

Comment: sadly color oracle isn't the real time i need. what color oracle does is take a screenshot of your screen and apply a filter, waht i want is to have my color blindness filter be active at all times, to simualte how a color blind person would see things on the secreen. the other link and the one in the comments didnt help either

Comment: Also https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorblindly/floniaahmccleoclneebhhmnjgdfijgg